# Tailwind CSS classes is not working in my project

Tags: css, class, tailwind-css

Here is my HTML link
https://play.tailwindcss.com/fbB4GCL0ht

#### Visual Studio Code setup pictures

[Tailwind.Config.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvyI4.jpg)

[All files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rk8tq.jpg)

> warn - No utility classes were detected in your source files. If this is unexpected, double-check the `content` option in your Tailwind CSS configuration. 
> warn - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration
> Done in 320ms.

This is showing my Visual Studio Code Terminal. What should I do? I have also added base components and utilities.

Comment: How did you intstall Tailwind?  Do you have a `tailwind.config.js` file in your project?  Without knowing what you've done and what file(s) you have, there's no way to diagnose the problem

Comment: Yeah I have that file

Comment: Edit your initial post to describe how you installed Tailwind, and add what that file currently has in it.  Also, did you add `@tailwind base;` `@tailwind components;` and `@tailwind utilities;` in your main CSS file

Comment: As you said I just added please help me with this problem.

Comment: https://github.com/ali09-github/Tailwind_project

Comment: If your avenues of solution fail to whatever degree, consider that Tailwind has caused you more trouble than its worth already and stop using it. One should never use Tailwind in a really large project because associated styles are not grouped - so then what real value does it bring? Small websites rapid development - but this is not the primary problems they claim to solve! (problems such as complex class naming, and avoid CSS rule collisions)

Answer (score 76):

This error is due to Tailwind not finding any classes to scan in what it 'thinks' is your HTML code directories.

This section in your `tailwind.config.js` file determines which files are scanned to be processed by Tailwind CSS:

```
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{html,js}',
    './components/**/*.{html,js}',
  ],
```

This corrected the issue for me.

Official documentation: *[Content Configuration](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration)*

Comment: https://github.com/ali09-github/Tailwind_project

Comment: also make sure to include the new app directory: './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',

Comment: Also, if you have not yet added a single tailwind class to your html, the same warning message will be in the console, something along the lines of "no utility classes were found", mind you this is the same warning message as if it cannot find your index.html at all.

Comment: If you use Next.js with MDX and have a `mdx-components.tsx` file for customizing built-in components, make sure to include this file in `tailwind.config.js` under `content` like `'./mdx-components.tsx',`

Answer (score 20):

I was facing the same problem. After some tests, I found a solution, but I don't know the right solution or why this is occurring, so if anyone has a clue, let us know.

```
content: [
    './pages/**/*.tsx',
    './components/**/*.tsx',
  ],
```

or

```
content: [
        './pages/**/*.jsx',
        './components/**/*.jsx',
      ],
```

Tailwind is not recognizing the options between {}, so I just specifying what type I'm working on, *.tsx* or *.jsx*. And I was leading to a wrong path, so check this, as well.

Comment: Experienced the same problem, very weird indeed.

Comment: Yes... the curly braces {} were the issue for me as well.  I'm using VueJS 3 in case that helps anyone.

Comment: I found that my mistake was that I have whitespaces in my paths. I accidentially had `.../*{js, jsx, ts, tsx}` but it should have been `.../*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}`.

Comment: you need to update the answer and state the project framework you are using. that syntax is VUE. Please update the answer.

Answer (score 17):

Although I added content in **tailwind.config**, it was still giving warnings.

I was running command to build the output:

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./input.css -o ./build/output.css
```

added -cli to the command and it worked for me:

```
npx tailwindcss-cli -i ./input.css -o ./build/output.css
```

Comment: This fixes it for me, why does this work?

Comment: Be careful with that, tailwindcss-cli hasn't been updated since 2020. It does fix the issue for me for some reason...

Comment: Wow, fixes the issue for me too. But why doesn't just 'npc tailwind-css' work? Have you been able to figure it out @GuidoTarsia?

Answer (score 11):

I had this issue too, but I may have solved it. Originally content in my `tailwind.config.js` file looked like this:

```
content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"]
```

I noticed that my App.js file was actually App.jsx so I just inserted single letter 'x' into that line:

```
content: ["./src/**/*.{html,jsx}"]
```

It seems to have worked.

Answer (score 9):

Your *tailwind.config.js* file can’t find your *index.html* file.

In the Tailwind CSS configuration file add your file path into content array `'./index.html',`

You have to define your file path into content like below:

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}",

  '*.{html,js}'], // Like this

  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

By the way, if you have different file extensions like .ts, .jsx, etc., you have to define the file extension in `content: ['./*.{html,js,ts,jsx}']`

Comment: The docs explicitly state to not use overly broad wild cards: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#pattern-recommendations

Answer (score 6):

Don't use the curly braces; instead, specify the following.

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './src/**/*.html',
    './src/**/*.js',
    './public/**/*.html',
    './public/**/*.js'
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: Curly braces are just fine and are used in the official docs extensively: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration

Answer (score 5):

If you use [Vite](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vite/info) then configure in file *tailwind.config.js*:

```
 content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./public/index.html"]
```

Or you use Yarn, Npm, etc... then configure in file *tailwind.config.js*:

```
 content: [
        "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
        "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    ],
```

Answer (score 5):

I think I've found the answer to the problem of Tailwind not building classes.

Besides the config of tailwind.config content sources, what really matters is:

***From which folder you start your app with ng serve***

For example, my *tailwind.config* file is:

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["app.component.html", "product/product.component.html", "home/home.component.html"]
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [], 
}
```

for Tailwind to find the classes in those three templates I have to start Angular from */src/app/* folder with `ng serve`.

If I start Angular from the */src/* folder then Tailwind will not find any classes.

Comment: this is a duplicate answer, using regex is optimal.

Comment: @chris_r what do you mean?

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same problem, the solution is to make sure your `content configuration` is correct. [refer](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration)

1. In your `tailwind.config.js`: Make sure the `content` source is pointing to your `HTML files` that are using tailwind. [refer](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#pattern-recommendations)

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './components/**/*.{html,js}',
    './pages/**/*.{html,js}',
    './index.html',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {}
  },
  plugins: []
}
```

2. Restart the Tailwind CLI build process

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch
```

** Ensure there are no warning messages regarding invalid file paths.

Comment: Great! this worked well for me. I'm using angular 15.2.3. I tried all the solutions above but none of them worked. I keep facing the same warning.

Comment: Oh finally worked, thanks!

Comment: please state the framework you are using. this helps when debugging.

Comment: @chris_r You can refer framework guide by tailwind docs  https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/framework-guides

Comment: The docs official recommend against overly broad wildcard patterns: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#pattern-recommendations

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other solutions, this can happen if you've changed the `prefix` value in your configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the file you are working on. For example, if you're working on *.js* and *.html* file then you need to specify it in your *tailwind.config.js* file like this:

```
content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"]
```

If you're also working on .jsx file, then you only have to add it to your configuration file:

```
content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js,jsx}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to into global.css

@tailwind variants;

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31358928)

Answer (score 1):

Like others said it depends if you are working with JS, TypeScript, or even HTML. In each case, you need to say the config to which files it will apply.

This is my config and I work with TypeScript:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    purge: ["./src/components/**/*.tsx", "./pages/**/*.tsx"],
    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    variants: {},
    plugins: [require("tailwindcss"), require("precss"), require("autoprefixer")],
};
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. This worked for me for my next.js project.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where some tailwind styles were working and other ones were not. After trying everything on this thread I got the impression that it could be something to do with adding the wrong object in the tailwind config. I remembered that I had added some bespoke fontsizes recently and had added this directly in the theme object. I moved it to the extension object and it worked immediately. For example:

Not working:

[image]

Working:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that in content, the string doesn't contain spaces: `{.js,.jsx}` instead of `{.js, .jsx}`.

Answer (score 1):

Originally I used it well, but when i builded a new project i found it was not working anymore. I have tried many solutions and tried to check what I did wrong, but in the end, i found it just a matter of path.
so i mean, you need to check the path, "./pages/......"or"./**src**/pages/......."

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. But when I started adding tailwind classes to the components and restarted the server, it's gone.

I think it might due to no class names found in any of the files it scanned.

Comment: Yeah! I have that same problem but now its fixed

Comment: This was why it showed up on my machine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had to delete my package-lock.json and recreate with `npm install`.

I had tried everything up and to that point but this worked.

Answer (score 1):

Some frameworks hide their main HTML entry point in a different place than the rest of your templates (often public/index.html), so if you are adding Tailwind classes to that file make sure it’s included in your configuration as well:

Don't forget your HTML entry point if applicable

tailwind.config.js

```
  content: [
    './public/index.html',
    './src/**/*.{html,js}',
  ],
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked when I removed the dot before the curly braces like
`content: ["./src/**/*{js, jsx,}"]`
or add them individually like
`content: ["./src/**/*{.js, .jsx,}"]`

I don't really understand why but I get an error when I configure it like
`content: ["./src/**/*.{js, jsx,}"]`

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you find out why this `warn` appear when using this `content: ["./src/**/*{.js, .jsx,}"]`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Vite inside a monorepo (turborepo). Prefixing the content glob with `__dirname` fixed it for me:

```js
{
  content: [
    __dirname + "./index.html", 
    __dirname + "/src/**/*{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone is playing around with only HTML and Tailwind CSS (no JavaScript), as I was :), you need a server running to serve the Tailwind CSS styles or adjust the path to where the CSS file is.

If you're using Visual Studio Code you can use for example the extension Live Server to start a server to host your static HTML files.

If you want to run your HTML file without a server, then make sure to adjust the link to the absolute path of your CSS file, e.g.: `<link href="/home/john/project/dist/output.css" rel="stylesheet">`

As mentioned above, when declaring multiple file types in the `tailwind.config.js` => `content` make sure to don't have any space between them! And always double-check your paths.

Happy styling with Tailwind CSS!

Comment: Re *"Visual Studio"*: Do you mean [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code)?

Comment: Yes :) I updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

You will also see this warning if you haven't actually set any class statements.

So, *if* you're starting a new project, and you're 100% sure your config file is correct, make sure you have at least one class statement in one of your files.

For example, add <div class="w-full"></div> as a test in your *index.html* file.

Answer (score 0):

The path may have been changed in your project. Check your path and configure accordingly. E.g., if you have moved your pages & components to your src folder, add the following to your Tailwind config file.

```
  content: [
    "./src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case, I had spaces before file extensions in *tailwind.config.js*.

Wrong version:

```
  content: [
      "./assets/**/*.{vue, js, ts, jsx, tsx}",
      "./templates/**/*.{html, twig}"
  ],
```

Correct version:

```
  content: [
      "./assets/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
      "./templates/**/*.{html,twig}"
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

It basically looks for your component files, so you have to configure the path that way.

Suppose you just started a react project, added tailwind, and you want to check. in that case you can add the following to your, tailwind.config.js file. This will locate the App.jsx file in your src directory of the project.

```
  content: [
    './src/.{html,jsx}',
  ],
```

On another case, if you have a components directory inside of which you different directories for different components you can add the following to your tailwind.config.js file.

```
  content: [
    './src/**/*.{html,jsx}',
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Import TailwindCSS into your pages/_app.js file:

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
import 'tailwindcss/tailwind.css';

function MyApp`enter code here`({ Component, pageProps }) {
return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation to your code - it is very hard to understand something when it isn't explained. Read - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Make sure your Tailwind config file doesn't contain duplicated properties. In my case, the content property had been repeated twice. After removing one of them it worked as supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue when doing an upgrade to 3.1.x from 2.2 and did not complete all the upgrade steps.

Specifically, I added the content entry but did not remove the purge entry

```
module.exports = {
  purge: [],
  content: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}']
```

After I removed the purge line, the util classes where included.

```
module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}']
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, check your path to your templates in *tailwind.config.js*.

Path might begin with `..` instead of `.`:

```
content: [
'../src/app/app.component.html'
]
```

instead of

```
content: [
'./src/app/app.component.html'
]
```

This was my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked in my case. I had to use path in the tailwind.config.js file to make it work.

```
const { join } = require('path');

module.exports = {
  content: [join(__dirname, 'src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}')],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that is using Tailwind with [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) and Tailwind CSS. Add this to your content value:

```
    content: [
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
  ],
```

***Attention!***

The warning will still there even if you corrected the content path,

> You need to add minimum one Tailwind CSS class to one of the paths you mentioned in content, just use a tailwind css in your project, and the warning will disappear. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a few things trying to get the styles to be applied with Tailwind CSS. I did eventually add the CDN script tag to my index which basically made the class styles pull through to the frontend.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
// CDN added which made everything work..is this a good approach?
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 class="text-3xl font-bold underline">
    Hello world!
  </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In production builds you want to avoid this option if you want to avoid the huge 4MB all-inclusive-file. Most people won't use most classes provided by TailwindCSS, so 4MB will shrink to perhaps 50K on a given project for production.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I thought you could tell by my tone of my submission that I was sad I could not get it to work and use tailwindcss for a side project. However I am working on a tailwindcss project at work so I'll look into why config isn't working. Thanks for the reasoning though!

Comment: Tailwind does not fully work with Angular Material Components without extra preprocessing configuration. Tailwind addresses a real css complexity challenge the wrong way.  

1) We WANT locally scoped / shadow dom css rules
2) We WANT all CSS classes to be covered INCLUDING rule names such as margin-inline-end - but they are not supported directly in Tailwind
3) We do not want brittle complex silently failing JIT compilation of classes 
4) We do not want to be at risk of Tailwind not supporting core CSS specs that come in the future


Do not use a library because it is trendy.

Answer (score 0):

I have also got the same error. Look at this configuration file:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./Components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Make sure if you create a folder of Components in your root folder, it should be Components in your *taiwind.config.js* file.

Answer (score 0):

After you read the Tailwind CSS installation carefully and did all the steps, *make* sure, when you run the project (`npm run` or `ng serve` or anything else) be at the same directory that *package.json* is.

Answer (score 0):

Just btw, when your `content` is bloated with a bunch of different file paths that have all the exact same pattern except for 1 folder like example:

```
content: [
  './src/app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
  './src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
  './src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx',
  './src/hooks/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
],
```

You can put the folder names in one like this:

```
content: ['./src/(app|pages|components|hooks)/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Please check the image for tailwind.config.js where it is being put and what is written on the file]

Check the files structure on the left side and run:

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./src/styles.css -o ./public/styles.css --watch
```

The smart Tailwind CSS will scan the folder for file and it will be successful!