# Angular tailwind utilities working fine in development, but not in production

Tags: angular, typescript, tailwind-css

When I build my Angular project I only sometimes get "No utility classes were detected in your source files." using tailwind, and sometimes it builds without warning but still no utilities. This happened all of a sudden, being built many times before, with working utilities. The base tailwind reset gets implemented in the styles, but not utilities..

It's also worth mentioning that classes i build from the styles with @apply works fine.

tailwind.config.js:

```
content: ["./src/**/*.{html,ts}"],
```

build command:

```
ng build --output-path docs
```

included in styles.css:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A coworker found a solution to this. For some unknown reason you have to include multiple file extensions to the tailwind config content string, even if they aren't used.

```
content: ["./src/**/*.{html,ts,tsx,jsx}"],
```

Comment: You saved my day! Any explanation about what happened?

Comment: Good to hear! :)
Still not sure why this happened specifically in Angular.

Comment: FYI: I faced today the same issue. Nothing in tailwind config was changed since last time. I've removed "tsx,jsx" since I don't have these kind of files, and then the build was fixed. Very strange.

Comment: This answer could explain that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73231393/1409595