# Tailwind CSS warning: No utility classes were detected in your source files

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css, vite

I make a vue project using this documentation: https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#creating-a-vue-application

And I wanted to added tailwind css to this project. So I used this guide (from point 2 `Install Tailwind CSS`): https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite#vue

But, I see no changes and get this warning:

```
warn - No utility classes were detected in your source files. If this is unexpected, double-check the `content` option in your Tailwind CSS configuration.
warn - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration
```

I followed the instuction as it is.
I tried following the content-configuration and I double checked it to see all files in place.

I was expecting `tailwind.config.cjs` file should be generated but instead `tailwind.config.js` is generated.

**Updates**:
On repeating all the steps using this link: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite#vue

At step 4:
`Add the Tailwind directives to your CSS`, When I replace the content for `style.css` as asked in the step.. Exactly after this point, the error is shown.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tailwind CSS classes is not working in my project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71070781/tailwind-css-classes-is-not-working-in-my-project)

Comment: @ericmp - No, I have looked into this. And I understand the reason, but I don't think that is the case for me.

Comment: Please be sure of it and share more context.

Comment: @YashMadhwal maybe you should consider start from 0 and install it this way - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite#vue (the link you shared). It's pretty quick, and you'll have vue3 + tailwind + vite

Comment: @ericmp pretty much what OP did already.

Comment: yeah but i meant it in case they are mixing both documentations (the one from vue and the one from tailwind). so yeah, in few minutes i have it running, i just followed the steps

Comment: To be honest, this is the first time I am facing such problem. For the previous projects, I didn't face such problem. @ericmp I have tried that version by Tailwind and didn't face the problem. But when I edited the content of Files, I faced such problem!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed.. Asking in the discord community this was the response:

> Thank you for supplying a remotely-hosted repository. It seems to work
> fine for me, it could be that you're suffering from a bug that this PR
> solves: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/pull/9650. You
> could temporarily try insiders version and see if that fixes it for
> you
> `npm install tailwindcss@insiders`

Answer (score 0):

I just gave solution to the same problem. You might have the same...

I had my tailwind.config.js like this:

```
module.exports = {
content: ["./src**/**/*.{html,js}"],
```

},

...and I changed the destination folder from "src" to "public", and it worked for me.

Like this:

```
module.exports = {
content: ["./public/**/*.{html,js}"],
```

},

Hope this will help you. Good luck and happy coding !

Comment: Why do you have your files in `public`? Quite strange.

Comment: Well, it wasn't working and I searched for some solutions, I saw this one and I thought it make sense , cause my html, css and js files are in this folder Public.

Comment: They should be in `assets` for bundle optimisations tbh. Got none of those in `public`, so you're shipping unoptimized assets to your clients.

Comment: So you are telling me I must replace my folder "src" into this "assets" folder ? Or create a new folder in my project called "assets"? My folder "src" is where I created my first CSS file , and I built it after instalation from "src" folder to "public" folder. This is why I am using 'public" folder, because the css file inside has all the tailwind cool stuff, plus my html and my JS file. I'm not really a pro...not yet ;) Thanks for your comments