# Tailwind not getting effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

i try to use tailwind css but   [it doesn't get effect on the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoiLN.png)  after i install it when i run the command
`tailwind -i ./src/input.css -o ./public/output.css` it does not work its showing me .

```
warn - No utility classes were detected in your source files. If this is unexpected, double-check the `content` option in your Tailwind CSS configuration.
warn - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration

Done in 1762ms.
```

i tried to change from

```
@tailwind based
@tailwind components
@tailwind utilities`
```

to

```
@import /tailwind based
@import /tailwind components
@import /tailwind utilities
```

but its doesn't  work its showing me the same warning, someone should help me through please!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tailwind CSS classes is not working in my project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71070781/tailwind-css-classes-is-not-working-in-my-project)

Answer (score 0):

Check the configuration file

```js
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './src/**/*.html',
    './src/**/*.js',
    // Add any other file types or paths your project uses
  ],
  // other configurations...
}
```

and Update to the latest Version. This should solve the problem. And also Verify the Script "package.json" file

Comment: i tried it but its doesn't  work broh

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).